# the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "Customer::displayCustomer"

Tags: c++, class, constants, member-functions

I'm currently working on a project for an online banking service and I keep running into the same problem here no matter what I try. The line in question I keep getting an error for is commented in the Account.cpp file

**Customer.h:**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMER_H
#define CUSTOMER_H

#include <string>

class Customer {
public:
    Customer();
    Customer(const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName, const std::string& address, const std::string& email);
    void displayCustomer();

private:
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    std::string address;
    std::string email;
};

#endif // CUSTOMER_H
```

**Customer.cpp:**

```
#include "Customer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

Customer::Customer() {
    // Default constructor
}

Customer::Customer(const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName, const std::string& address, const std::string& email)
    : firstName(firstName), lastName(lastName), address(address), email(email) {
    // Overloaded constructor
}

void Customer::displayCustomer() {
    std::cout << "Name: " << firstName << " " << lastName << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address: " << address << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Email: " << email << std::endl;
}
```

**Account.h:**

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H
#include "Customer.h"

class Account {

public:

    Account();

    Account(int accountNumber, double balance, const Customer& user);

    double getBalance() const;

    void setBalance(double balance);

    virtual bool deposit(double amount) = 0;

    virtual bool withdraw(double amount) = 0;

    virtual void displayAccount() const;

protected:

    int accountNumber;

    double balance;

    Customer user;

};

#endif // ACCOUNT_H
```

**Account.cpp:**

```
#include "Account.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

Account::Account() {

    // Default constructor

}

Account::Account(int accountNumber, double balance, const Customer& user)

    : accountNumber(accountNumber), balance(balance), user(user) {

    // Overloaded constructor

}

double Account::getBalance() const {

    return balance;

}

void Account::setBalance(double balance) {

    this->balance = balance;

}

void Account::displayAccount() const {

    std::cout << "Account number: " << accountNumber << std::endl;

    user.displayCustomer();

    std::cout << "Balance: $" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << balance << std::endl;

}
```

**CheckingAccount.h:**

```
#ifndef CHECKINGACCOUNT_H
#define CHECKINGACCOUNT_H

#include "Account.h"

class CheckingAccount : public Account {
public:
    CheckingAccount();
    CheckingAccount(int accountNumber, double balance, const Customer& user, double transactionFee);
    double getTransactionFee() const;
    bool deposit(double amount) override;
    bool withdraw(double amount) override;
    void displayAccount() const override;

private:
    double transactionFee;
};

#endif // CHECKINGACCOUNT_H
```

**CheckingAccount.cpp:**

```
#include "CheckingAccount.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

CheckingAccount::CheckingAccount()
    : transactionFee(5.0) {
    // Default constructor
}

CheckingAccount::CheckingAccount(int accountNumber, double balance, const Customer& user, double transactionFee)
    : Account(accountNumber, balance, user), transactionFee(transactionFee) {
    // Overloaded constructor
}

double CheckingAccount::getTransactionFee() const {
    return transactionFee;
}

bool CheckingAccount::deposit(double amount) {
    if (amount >= 0) {
        double newBalance = getBalance() + amount - transactionFee;
        setBalance(newBalance);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool CheckingAccount::withdraw(double amount) {
    if (amount >= 0 && amount <= getBalance()) {
        double newBalance = getBalance() - amount - transactionFee;
        setBalance(newBalance);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void CheckingAccount::displayAccount() const {
    std::cout << "Checking Account ----" << std::endl;
    Account::displayAccount();
    std::cout << "Transaction fee: $" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << transactionFee << std::endl;
}
```

**SavingsAccount.h:**

```
#ifndef SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
#define SAVINGSACCOUNT_H

#include "Account.h"

class SavingsAccount : public Account {
public:
    SavingsAccount();
    SavingsAccount(int accountNumber, double balance, const Customer& user, double interestRate);
    double getInterestRate() const;
    double calcInterest();
    void displayAccount() const override;

private:
    double interestRate;
};

#endif // SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
```

**SavingsAccount.cpp:**

```
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount()
    : interestRate(0.02) {
    // Default constructor
}

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(int accountNumber, double balance, const Customer& user, double interestRate)
    : Account(accountNumber, balance, user), interestRate(interestRate) {
    // Overloaded constructor
}

double SavingsAccount::getInterestRate() const {
    return interestRate;
}

double SavingsAccount::calcInterest() {
    double interest = getBalance() * interestRate;
    setBalance(getBalance() + interest);
    return interest;
}

void SavingsAccount::displayAccount() const {
    std::cout << "Savings Account ----" << std::endl;
    Account::displayAccount();
    std::cout << "Interest rate: " << interestRate * 100 << "%" << std::endl;
}
```

**Tester.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Account.h"
#include "CheckingAccount.h"
#include "SavingsAccount.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int selection = 0;
    string firstName, lastName, address, email;
    double amount;

    // Input user's information
    cout << "Enter your first name: ";
    cin >> firstName;
    cout << "Enter your last name: ";
    cin >> lastName;
    cout << "Enter your address: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, address);
    cout << "Enter your email: ";
    cin >> email;

    // Create a Customer object
    Customer customer(firstName, lastName, address, email);

    // Create CheckingAccount and SavingsAccount objects
    CheckingAccount checkingAccount(1111, 0.0, customer, 5.0);
    SavingsAccount savingsAccount(2222, 0.0, customer, 0.02); // Also running into error here "object of abstract class type "SavingsAccount" is not allowed

    cout << "Your checking account and savings account are created successfully." << endl << endl;

    while (selection != 8) {
        cout << "Please select a service from the menu:" << endl;
        cout << "1. Display accounts" << endl;
        cout << "2. Deposit to checking account" << endl;
        cout << "3. Deposit to savings account" << endl;
        cout << "4. Withdraw from checking account" << endl;
        cout << "5. Withdraw from savings account" << endl;
        cout << "6. Transfer money from checking to savings" << endl;
        cout << "7. Transfer money from savings to checking" << endl;
        cout << "8. Exit" << endl;
        cin >> selection;

        switch (selection) {
            case 1:
                checkingAccount.displayAccount();
                savingsAccount.displayAccount();
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Enter the amount to deposit to checking account: ";
                cin >> amount;
                if (checkingAccount.deposit(amount)) {
                    cout << "Deposit is successful." << endl;
                } else {
                    cout << "Invalid deposit amount." << endl;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Enter the amount to deposit to savings account: ";
                cin >> amount;
                if (savingsAccount.deposit(amount)) {
                    cout << "Deposit is successful." << endl;
                } else {
                    cout << "Invalid deposit amount." << endl;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "Enter the amount to withdraw from checking account: ";
                cin >> amount;
                if (checkingAccount.withdraw(amount)) {
                    cout << "Withdraw is successful." << endl;
                } else {
                    cout << "Invalid withdrawal amount or insufficient balance." << endl;
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "Enter the amount to withdraw from savings account: ";
                cin >> amount;
                if (savingsAccount.withdraw(amount)) {
                    cout << "Withdraw is successful." << endl;
                } else {
                    cout << "Invalid withdrawal amount or insufficient balance." << endl;
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                cout << "Enter the amount to transfer from checking to savings: ";
                cin >> amount;
                if (checkingAccount.withdraw(amount) && savingsAccount.deposit(amount)) {
                    cout << "Transfer is successful." << endl;
                } else {
                    cout << "Invalid transfer amount or insufficient balance in checking account." << endl;
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                cout << "Enter the amount to transfer from savings to checking: ";
                cin >> amount;
                if (savingsAccount.withdraw(amount) && checkingAccount.deposit(amount)) {
                    cout << "Transfer is successful." << endl;
                } else {
                    cout << "Invalid transfer amount or insufficient balance in savings account." << endl;
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                cout << "Thanks for using Bank of Wake!" << endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid selection." << endl;
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you really sure this comprises a [mcve] of your actual problem as required here?? I'd bet most of the code you posted is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I mainly wanted to see if somehow the error was connected to any other files in the project. Also for some reason the comment I meant to add did not show on the file I meant to add it to. It's in Account.cpp:

Comment: user.displayCustomer(); // This is the line in question in the "void Account::displayAccount()" class

Comment: Didn't your compiler tell you th exact source of your error??

Comment: `displayCustomer` isn't a const function so you can't call it from inside another const function. Solution is to make it const like many of the other functions in this code.

Comment: It is rather obvious that approximately 97% of the shown code has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with the compilation error. The chances of getting a useful answer on Stackoverflow are increased significantly if the shown code meets all requirements for a [mre], as explained in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

You may not call a non-constant member function from a constant member function.

Within the class `Customer` the member function `displayCustomer` is a non-constant member finction:

```
void displayCustomer();
```

But it is called from constant member functions as for example from the function `displayAccount` of the class `Account`

```
void Account::displayAccount() const {

    std::cout << "Account number: " << accountNumber << std::endl;

    user.displayCustomer();

    std::cout << "Balance: $" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << balance << std::endl;

}
```

Within a constant member function the object for which the function is called is considered as a constant object. That is members of such an object are accessed using the pointer `this` of the type `const class_object *`. There is no implicit conversion from a pointer to a constant object to a pointer to a non-constant object.

Declare the member function `displayCustomer` as a constant function

```
void displayCustomer() const;
```